# try to list out all the tweet for my tweetpy and add the location filter in my

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to make a sentimental analysis in London's garden comment, but I can't **add the geolocation in London** and **can't format a list** of these tweet:(

but it shows **for tweet in tweets:
TypeError: 'Cursor' object is not iterable**

after that, I was trying to follow the YouTube tutorial to create a if loop to clean data.I want to delete **the RT, #hashtag, @mention and HTTP link** . but I can't find a efficient way to clean the data

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

#sentiment Analysis

keyword = ["Park","garden"]
noOfTweet = 500
date_since = "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"
date_until= "2020-12-31T00:00:00Z"

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,
query = keyword,
start_time = date_since,
end_time = date_until,
tweet_mode ='extend',
geocode = "-0.098369,51.513557,70km",
lang ='en',
count = noOfTweet)

#try to format a list 
all.tweets = []
for i in tweets:
    all.tweets.append(i)

for tweet in tweets:
    final_text = tweet.text.replace('RT','')
    if final_text.startswith(' @'):
        position = final_text.index(':')
        final_text = final_text[position+2:]
    elif final_text.startswith('@'):
        position = final_text.index(' ')
        final_text = final_text[position + 2:]
```

Comment: Please: 1. show a sample of your dataframe, and 2. show a sample dataframe containing your expected output.

Comment: I am so sorry, I am just new in python. I don't have any idea about creating a  dataframe. but I would like my dataframe could be tweet and geolocation of each tweet

Comment: The search API you are using can only return Tweets from the past 7 day.